# How to Not Submit a Form Using AJAXToolkit AutoComplete Extender?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used AJAXToolkit AutoComplete extender in my project.It works fines.But the issue is with the form of the page.
when i type in the AutoComplete, i get list of suggestions.When i click on the page other than the Autocomplete, the form gets submitted.
any suggestions how to stop submission of entire form whenever i click on the page?I use .net 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Does your TextBox have AutoPostBack="True" set?  If so, it will automatically postback when you're "finished" (when the input control loses focus).  If this is the case, just set it to false.

Comment: yeah,My TextBox AutoPostBack was set to true which i have changed it to false, now.

but i have a url attached to each of my suggestions.On click of suggestion, user gets navigated to that particular url. When i do AutoPostback= "false", i wont get navigated to that page.

HOw do i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

yeah,My TextBox AutoPostBack was set to true which i have changed it to false, now.

but i have a url attached to each of my suggestions.On click of suggestion, user gets navigated to that particular url. When i do AutoPostback= "false", i wont get navigated to that page.

HOw do i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as simple as adding a required validator to your element to see if the user selected anything.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to add an event handler that detects clicks.  When a click occurs, stop the browser.  Let me know if you need code.